# How to set OnItemClickListener getdata from DBHelper which using AssetHelper?

Tags: android, sqlite, dictionary, fragment, onitemclicklistener

I made an dictionary application. It can search well, that shows on a listview.
but my problem is I want to make the list item clickable and go to a new fragment as a detail of words.

How to get the data for my new fragment?
I don't know how to create an adapter for that or to set the detail layout text.
what should i do?

Here's my code:

1. DBHelper.java

```js
    public class DBHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

     private static final String DB_NAME = "kamus";
     private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

     private static final String TB_DATA = "data";

     private static final String COL_ID = "_id";
     private static final String COL_IND = "ind";
     private static final String COL_KOR = "kor";
     private static final String COL_ROM = "rom";
     private static final String COL_PLUS = "plus";
     private static final String COL_AUDIO = "audio";

     private static DBHelper dbInstance;
     private static SQLiteDatabase db;

     public DBHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
     }

     public static DBHelper getInstance(Context context) {
      if (dbInstance == null) {
       dbInstance = new DBHelper(context);
       db = dbInstance.getWritableDatabase();
      }
      return dbInstance;
     }

    public Cursor getIndo(String s) throws SQLException {
      Cursor mCursor = DBHelper.db.query(TB_DATA, null, COL_IND + " like '"
        + s + "%'", null, null, null, null);
      if (mCursor != null) {
       mCursor.moveToFirst();
       Log.v("getdata", "mCursor not null" + mCursor.getCount());
      }
      return mCursor;
     }


     @Override
     public synchronized void close() {
      dbInstance.close();
     }
    }
```

2. Fragment search IndoKorea.Java

```js
public class IndoKorea extends Fragment {

 private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
 protected static final Class<DetailInko> DetailInko = null;
 ListAdapter list_adapter;
 Cursor cursor;
 DBHelper dbHelper;
 EditText editSearch;
 ListView list;

 public IndoKorea() {
  // Required empty public constructor
 }

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater,
   ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle bundle) {
  // Inflate the layout for this fragment
  // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_indokorea, container,
  // false);
  View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_indokorea,
    viewGroup, false);
  
 
  editSearch = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.cari1);
  list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listKata1);

  dbHelper = DBHelper.getInstance(getActivity());
  
  editSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
     int count) {
    String text = editSearch.getText().toString().trim();

    cursor = dbHelper.getIndo(text);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() >= 0) {
     SimpleCursorAdapter list_adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
       getActivity(), R.layout.list_inko, cursor,
       new String[] { "ind", "kor", "rom" }, new int[] {
         R.id.textIndo, R.id.textHangeul,
         R.id.textRomanisasi });
     list.setAdapter(list_adapter);
    }
   }

   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
     int after) {



   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

   }
  });

  list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
     int position, long id) {
//         cursor.moveToFirst();
//    for(int i = 0; i< position; i++){
//     cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    
    
   }

  });
  
  return view;
 }


 public static IndoKorea newInstance(int i) {
  IndoKorea frag = new IndoKorea();
  Bundle args = new Bundle();
  args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i);
  frag.setArguments(args);
  return frag;
 }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  }

}
```

3. Detail of word .xml

```js
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="pack.esa.kikwa.DetailInko"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_kamus" >

     <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        
        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            >
            
            <TextView 
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/korean"
                />
            <View 
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
             android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                />
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >
                <LinearLayout 
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
                    >
                    <TextView 
                        android:textSize="50sp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/hangeul"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="AAA"
               android:singleLine="true"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/romanisasi"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Medium text"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            
            
            <View 
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="2.5dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
             android:text="@string/indonesia" />
            <View 
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" 
                android:layout_width="100dp" 
                android:layout_height="1dp" 
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"  />
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <ScrollView 
                    android:id="@+id/scrollView1" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
                    
                    <LinearLayout 
                        android:orientation="vertical" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                        
                        <TextView 
                            android:textSize="18sp" 
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
                            android:id="@+id/artiIndonesia" 
                            android:layout_width="270dp" 
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                            android:maxWidth="300dp" 
                            android:minWidth="299dp" 
                            android:text="kata indonesia" />
                        
                           <TextView 
                            android:textSize="18sp" 
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
                            android:id="@+id/artiPlus" 
                            android:layout_width="270dp" 
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                            android:maxWidth="300dp" 
                            android:minWidth="299dp" 
                            android:text="ini deskripsi kata" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    
                </ScrollView>
                <Button
                    android:layout_gravity="right" 
                    android:id="@+id/buttonSound"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"  
                    android:layout_width="35dp" 
                    android:layout_height="35dp" 
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
                    android:src="@drawable/soundsmall" />
                
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

-Thank You-

Comment: I already solved my problem.